# Can't start Eclipse Luna SR2 on Windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Tags: java, windows-8.1, eclipse-luna

I want to learn how to program apps for Android, and have both a new build of Java installed as well as Eclipse Luna SR2 downloaded and extracted. However, it seems I am running into a problem in starting up; I'm not sure how to solve the issue, unless it could be that I need to change the Runtime Environment variables.

Here's the message the dialog box displays when I try to run the program through Command Prompt:

```
Java was started but returned exit code= 13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion= 1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\Uses\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse Luna\eclipse\eclipsec.exe
-name Eclipsec
--launcher.library C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v
20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll
-startup C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\\plugins/org.clipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 100c_84
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion= 1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Could you please help me out here?

Comment: what is windows version..is it 32bit or what

Comment: Excuse me; I forgot to mention that in my original question... It's 64-bit.

Comment: Start eclipse in command line with -consoleLog argument, which will output the log messages to the std output. Then we might tell what's wrong.

Comment: It does output something to the std output, but it only displays for a fraction of a second before the window displaying it closes up and I get the error dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: go to `System > Advanced system setting > Environment Variables`

Under `System variables` :

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

remove this

hope this helps

Comment: Got it! The program opens up nicely now; I simply don't know if it will be the same effect for anyone else who is having trouble with this as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess based on what I see here is that the JRE "bitness" doesn't match Eclipse.

What do you get when you type "java -version" on the command prompt?

If it's telling you that you've installed a 32-bit version of Java, you'll need to change that to a 64-bit version.

Also... "-startup C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\Eclipse
Luna\eclipse\plugins/org.clipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar" looks suspicious. There's a missing "e" in "...org.clipse.equinox...". Did you modify the eclipse.ini file?

Comment: I did not modify the eclipse.ini file at all. I simply left out the e in that "startup" command you're referring to because I was typing up the message from the dialog box which didn't let me copy and paste the text from it. And I didn't felt like uploading a photo on Dropbox then sharing the link here.

This is what I get when I type "java -version":
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)